# OpenCV: PNG image with alpha channel

Tags: c++, opencv, png

I'm new to OpenCV and I've done a small POC for reading an image from some URL.
I'm reading the image from an URL using video capture. The code is as follows:

```
VideoCapture vc;
vc.open("http://files.kurento.org/img/mario-wings.png");
if(vc.isOpened() && vc.grab()) 
{
       cv::Mat logo;
       vc.retrieve(logo);
       cv::namedWindow("t");
       imwrite( "mario-wings-opened.png", logo);
       cv::imshow("t", logo);
       cv::waitKey(0);
       vc.release();
}
```

This image is not opened correctly, possibly due to alpha channel. 
What is the way to preserve alpha channel and get the image correctly?

Any help is appreciated.
-Thanks

**Expected output**

[image: Expected output]

**Actual output**

[image: Actual output]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you are only loading an image, I recommend you to use [imread](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#imread) instead, also, you will need to specified the second parameter of `imread` to load the alpha channel too, that is `CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED` or `cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED`, depending on the version (in the worst case a -1 also works).

As far as I know, the `VideoCapture`class do not load images/video with a 4th channel. Since you are using a web url, loading the image won't work with `imread`, but you may use any method to download the data (curl for example) and then use [imdecode](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#imdecode) with the data buffer to get the `cv::Mat`. OpenCV is a library for image processing, not for downloading images.

Comment: The new name is IMREAD_UNCHANGED

Comment: @Miki I think both works... in newer versions, not sure in which version it was introduced though, so I better leave both :)

Comment: Sure.. It's just the new name

Comment: I have a server through which I'll be doing video processing. This image will go on top of every frame.

I had tried curl before, but it had raised a lot of dependency issues with the server. Hence I had switched to VideoCapture.

But, I'll look into the alternatives you have suggested. Thanks!

Comment: @AVB Well, if you only want to overlay an image you can try python... that has a native module that can download a file and has opencv too, also you may try asking in stackoverflow help for the curl part. If it is always the same logo, won't it be better to just save the logo? Another thing you can try is setting the transparency  to a color that can be removed later on... for the blending use the `addweighted` function

Comment: @api55 The logo can be changed dynamically... Also the server that I'm using has a tool that generates the basic structure automatically for me in C++. Hence the complications... Setting transparency sounds promising, will try that... :)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna draw it over another image you can do that:

```
/**
 * @brief Draws a transparent image over a frame Mat.
 * 
 * @param frame the frame where the transparent image will be drawn
 * @param transp the Mat image with transparency, read from a PNG image, with the IMREAD_UNCHANGED flag
 * @param xPos x position of the frame image where the image will start.
 * @param yPos y position of the frame image where the image will start.
 */
void drawTransparency(Mat frame, Mat transp, int xPos, int yPos) {
    Mat mask;
    vector<Mat> layers;

    split(transp, layers); // seperate channels
    Mat rgb[3] = { layers[0],layers[1],layers[2] };
    mask = layers[3]; // png's alpha channel used as mask
    merge(rgb, 3, transp);  // put together the RGB channels, now transp insn't transparent 
    transp.copyTo(frame.rowRange(yPos, yPos + transp.rows).colRange(xPos, xPos + transp.cols), mask);
}
```